# Програму налаштовують чи настроюють?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, синоніми

В СУМ-11 надано такі значення дієслів настроювати і налаштовувати:

> НАСТРО́ЮВАТИ, юю, юєш, недок., НАСТРО́ЇТИ, о́ю, о́їш, док., перех.
>
> 2. Налагоджувати, регулювати, робити придатним для роботи (верстат, механізм і т. ін.). Учні.. повинні навчитися керувати фрезерним
>    верстатом, настроювати верстат для виконання різних робіт з
>    фрезерування (Методика викладання фрезерної справи, 1958, 223);
>    Досвідчені механізатори.. настроїли свої машини так, що ланкам
>    доводиться доочищати не більше 10 процентів коренів [буряків]
>    (Колгоспник України, 11, 1958, 4);
>
> НАЛАШТОВУВАТИ, ую, уєш, недок., НАЛАШТУВАТИ, ую, уєш, док., перех.
>
> 1. Готувати що-небудь; приводити в стан готовності. — Не знаєте, чи хазяїн уже устали? — спитався він. — Казали, сьогодні кудись їхати,
>    так щоб віз налаштувати (Панас Мирний, I, 1954, 242); Уляна висипала з
>    пелени квасолю і вже хотіла йти до хати, щоб налаштувати їжу кабанцеві
>    (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 454).
> 2. Робити що-небудь придатним для роботи, використання і т. ін. — Під час вечері Мишуня налаштовував радіоприймача (Юрій Яновський, II,
>    1954, 139).

Щодо вживання цих синонімів у конкретному контексті у [блозі проф. Пономарева](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2013/11/131118_ponomariv_blog2_ko) є таке зауваження:

> Щодо музичних інструментів, то краще казати настроювати, настроїти. А
> налаштовують, лаштують вози. Порівняймо: "Звечора було ще налаштувати
> віз". "Як дудку настроїш, так вона грає". (Зі словника за редакцією
> Бориса Грінченка).
>
> "Настрой свою ліру гучну, невидиму. Струна струні стиха нехай
> промовля". (Леся Українка).

А як бути з програмами, особистим кабінетом на сайті і т.ін.? Налаштовувати чи настроювати?

Comment: Див. також: [«Як краще перекласти „you can configure application…“?»](/q/5443).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/)

> ***Настроювати*** — налагоджувати, регулювати, робити придатним для роботи;
>   припасовувати якусь систему (програмне забезпечення, прилад, пристрій
>   тощо) до потреб користувача;
>
> АЛЕ:
>
> ***Налаштовувати*** — готувати що-небудь, виконувати початкову підготовку
>   системи до роботи.
>
> *Для з’єднання з мережею налаштуйте маршрутизатор (користувач уперше
>   готує систему до подальшого використання).*

Отже, ***настроїти***  особистий кабінет, але ***налаштувати*** програму